# How to change active menu item style in html/css/js/php

Tags: php, html, css, menu, navbar

heres how my html is

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?content=about">About us</a></li>
</ul>
```

as you can see the content of "about us" page is loaded in to index.php. 
now i want to change active page link on nav bar different style.

please do help me. i hope this question is clear.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This can be done a few ways using Javascript or PHP and CSS

Comment: add the <a> or <li> a class based on the $_GET array content and style it using CSS; now it's up to you

Comment: need to expand a little more on what you tried (per @paul) and what you are trying to accomplish with examples of why yours didn't work.  something to look at wouyld be `if($_GET['content']=='about'){ # do something }else{ # do default}`

Comment: thanks @Dave . if($_GET['content']=='gallery') {
 echo 'class="active"';
} that worked for me.. but is there a better alternative than that ? now you know what i was aiming for right

Comment: are you trying to just highlight that particular `<li>` or something?

Comment: yes. i want the active nav item to highlight and others to be not active .

Comment: Create a .active class & apply to the current li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to add a class to a particular item based on selection;

```
<ul class="navigation"> 
<li <?php if(!isset($_GET['content'])) { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> 
<li <?php if(isset($_GET['content']) && $_GET['content']=='about') { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="index.php?content=about">About us</a></li> 
</ul>
```